# Animating the width of a DIV or SPAN in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have tried doing this but with out success *(all this stuff is so easy in jQuery. arrrrr!!!)*

I have tried the following *(and various permutations)* but without success:

```
<body>
<span id="responseMsg" style="width:250px">Hi There</span>
</body>
```

JS:

```
dojo.animateProperty({
    node: dojo.byId("responseMsg"), duration: 1000,
    properties: {
        backgroundColor: { start: "white", end: "#66CC00" }
    }
}).play();
dojo.animateProperty({
    node: dojo.byId("responseMsg"), duration: 1000,
    properties: {
        width: 0
    }
}).play();
```

I have fiddled it up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VfEye/) so you can see what I mean. *(I'm guessing dojo animates css properties not tag variables)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your span-element a block-level-layout and it should work.

```
<span id="responseMsg" style="width:250px;display:block;">Hi There</span>
```

By the way, inline-css is very hard to maintain.

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VfEye/1/

Comment: That runs perfect. Add `white-space: nowrap;` and the text does not fold as it contracts. Do you know why the text is visible outside of the div as it is contracting?

Comment: Yes, just add  `overflow:hidden` to your css-rule and the text should be cut when resizing.